# How could I add screen recording functionality to Ziggeo Player?

Tags: video, media-player, screen-recording

I have read in docs about embedded screen record functionality in Ziggeo player. As I understand from it, I need to install an extension in browser but I have no idea how I could connect it with my app. 
Could you please advice me something?

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Firefox, you don't need to add anything to your existing Ziggeo embedding as it has direct support for screen recording. You only need the extension if you're not using FireFox (i.e chrome or opera).

First, you have to build the extension on the Ziggeo dashboard by going to Dashboard. Then select your `Application` -> `Manage` -> `extension builder`. You'll just have to input the necessary information (name, version, etc.) Then click

Next, you'll need to submit the file into Chrome Webstore https://chrome.google.com/webstore and/or Opera's addon page https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions

After you build and uploaded your extension, simply add the following lines to your Ziggeo embedding:

```
chrome_extension_id: "EXT-ID",
chrome_extension_install_link: "https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/EXT-NAME/EXT- 
ID"
```

and/or for Opera:

```
opera_extension_id: "EXT-ID",
opera_extension_install_link: "https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/INTERNAL-ID"
```

These lines should be included within your application embedding, so your full embedding should look like the following:

```
new ZiggeoApi.V2.Application({
...,
chrome_extension_id: "EXT-ID",
chrome_extension_install_link: "https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/EXT-NAME/EXT- 
ID"
})
```

and/or for Opera:

```
new ZiggeoApi.V2.Application({
...,
opera_extension_id: "EXT-ID",
opera_extension_install_link: "https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/INTERNAL-ID"
})
```

Along with the rest of your embedding details like your app token and any other options.

Please refer to this page for more info:
https://ziggeo.com/features/screen-recording